# Dark Souls 2: What is the largest weapon?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Does anyone know what the largest weapon in the game is? By largest I mean physically largest, not highest damage or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually Greatswords (my personal favorite kind of weapon) are the biggest category and are large. Like the other above, the biggest one probably is the Smelter Hammer.

Answer (score 0):

From watching a bunch of Youtube videos I'd say it's the [Smelter Hammer](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Smelter+Hammer) from Crown of the Iron King.